# Why are there two default image options in an image field

Tags: entities, nodes

When you create a field of type image in Drupal 7, there are two default image fields.

One is in settings and the other is in field settings. There is a message with each of those two settings, but I still don't understand how they are different. In each case, they upload to the **sites/default/files/default_images** folder.

What is the difference between the two settings fields?

Answer (score 2):

One is the default image information for that field as a global entity, while the other is specific to that instance of the field. Fields can be re-used across different content types, so the global default would apply to every content type that used that field, unless those content types override that behaviour with their own specific default.

Comment: So, the explanation for my client is whether they want the default image to be available to other content types or not. It seems that might affect Views too.

Comment: essentially.  One example: ecommerce site with 10 different product types. In order to keep views or other similar devices simple, you reuse certain fields like image, description, price, etc. but each product type also contains it's own unique fields like size, weight, etc. You could use the global default for the images to ensure all product types use the same default placeholder, but could override any of them individually to provide product type specific placeholders

Comment: "Default image" (the content type specific one has the description:) 
If no image is uploaded, this image will be shown on display and will override the field's default image.

"Default image" (the global one has the description:) 
If no image is uploaded, this image will be shown on display.